# Correct way to pass multiple values for same parameter name in GET request in Sails

Tags: node.js, sails.js, sails-mongo

I'm looking into what is the correct way to pass multiple values for the same parameter name in a GET request in sails, but dont know how to achieve this.

I have seen url like this

```
http://url/action?id=a&id=b 
http://url/action?id=x,y,z
```

So, can someone point me at an official reference source or any example?

Comment: do you send this values from a html page?

Comment: I need to call get API.

Answer (score 0):

So if you need to send multiple ids by using get, you can send array inside get params...

So url should look like this:

http://url/action?id[]=1&id[]=2&id=3

In controller you can get this values with
var ids = req.param("id");

You will get this -> ids = ["1", "2", "3"]

Comment: sails having inbuilt crud operation, so i am wondering sails support this.

Comment: Well, thats another question :)

But you can do it like this:

http://url/action?where={"id":["something","something else"]}